# Tinyscrollbar not working with drag

Tags: screen-resolution, overlapping, tinyscrollbar

I use the tinyscrollbar plugin on a site in a couple of sections.
So far, it was working great. But now for some reason, the scroll is avaible with the mousewheel but not with the drag/drop slider..

The resolution i'm using is 1360x768, but I test it in a 1920x1080 and the drag WORKS! 
I check with firebug if the problem is an overlapping element over the slider but I can't see anything..

I didn't post any code, because I didn't make any changes on tinyscrollbar.js..

Comment: I've checked that on a 1920x1080 resolution, resizing the browser doesn't affect the drag slider.. it keeps working..

Comment: New observation, I was using chrome.. it works fine in firefox here  and chrome of other machines.. so it must be a problem of extensions or something like that

Comment: Does the example at http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/ work for you currently?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to windows 8 there is a bug where it only registers screen touch instead of both the screen and mouse... so you will need to address that

Answer (score 0):

Check the z-index of the scroll bar element places it ontop of everything else (an arbitarily high z-index is fine for this purpose) as this can sometimes end up behind the custom scroll viewport meaning that when you go to drag the scroll bar you click on the wrong element.